# Are there any restricted zones in Los Angeles where I should not go with bicycle/skateboard?

Tags: bicycles, los-angeles, hollywood

I usually explore cities with a combination of a bicycle, electric skatebord and public transit system and in New York City I had no problem whatsoever and could go anywhere. I was happy to see bike lanes all around Wall Street and other famous landmarks.

This time I am going to Los Angeles, and I would like to do the same. I imagine there is strict security in some parts because of the famous residents.

Will there be any problem with me riding through Hollywood, Beverly Hills, etc?

Comment: I should imagine Hollywood and Beverly Hills quite safe, as is most of LA.

Comment: Your main problem will be that distances in LA are much further than New York.

Comment: I use metro for long distances and then electric skateboard / bike sharing to explore locally for up to 30km (then I am exhausted:)).

Comment: Much of the residential parts of what people associate with "Hollywood" involves some combination of steep, windy, and narrow, with little regard for non-automobile traffic. I would be more concerned about that than "strict security".

Comment: I will see, especially if the roads are really narrow that could be a problem. I don't have any problems with stamina since I cycle 50km+/day in the Alps and I bet Hollywood is not as steep as that:)

Comment: I'm not aware of any special restrictions for bikes.  Any public road open to cars would be open to bikes (except freeways, etc).  Electric skateboards are likely to have restrictions by traffic law, but that wouldn't have anything to do with security or famous people.

Comment: Note that LA hasn't got much of a metro.  Buses can be slow and may not have bike racks available.

Comment: Speaking of buses, [here's a fun video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5stBO1wOv4). Los Angeles is still trying to figure out how bike lanes work. It's legal to ride on sidewalks within the city of L.A. if you do it safely, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of in the way of a *legal* restriction (as opposed to "just don't try it, just don't.") that may catch some tourists by surprise is [the banning of bicycles from anywhere but paved roads within Griffith Park](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jan/02/local/la-me-bicycle-plan-20110102). The nicely maintained trails and fire roads might be tempting, but don't do it. The equestrians will do their very best to have you arrested, as they consider it a serious threat to their safety.